# Android SDK Visualizer getWaveForm method

Tags: android, wave

When I call getWaveForm method of Visualizer class, I get data perfectly using this  http://vprbbc.streamguys.net/vprbbc24.mp3 audio. But when I try to use my 4/5 seconds length audio, sometimes it returns all -128 in my byte array, and sometimes it returns different values.  But different values are correct, all -128 values are not correct.

This can not be a solution, I need a stable solution. I need getWaveForm method will return different values (not all -128).

Any idea?

-Arefin

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you find a solution?